# Pan Gesture making view jump away from finger on drag

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm having a problem when trying to drag a view using a pan gesture recognizer. The view is a collectionViewCell and the dragging code is working, except when the drag starts the view jumps up and to the left. My code is below.

In the collectionViewCell:

```swift
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(detectPan))
    self.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer]
}

var firstLocation = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    var lastLocation = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    @objc func detectPan(_ recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            firstLocation = recognizer.translation(in: self.superview)
            lastLocation = recognizer.translation(in: self.superview)
        case .changed:
            let translation  = recognizer.translation(in: self.superview)
            self.center = CGPoint(x: lastLocation.x + translation.x, y: lastLocation.y + translation.y)
        default:
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                self.center = self.firstLocation
            }
        }
    }
```

The first image is before the drag starts, the second is what happens when dragging up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe that your .changed case shouldn't be using self.center.

Comment: @xTwisteDx What should I use instead?

Comment: Actually, just use translation instead of the last location + translation. Try that.. Sorry, don't have XCode atm so I can't test. I think what actually might be happening is you're modifying your set last location and then adding a translation. Notice the view goes up and to the left. That indicates that it's overcalculating something.

Comment: @xTwisteDx Ah! I figured it out. Your first guess was right, I should've been updating the frame.origin.y and frame.origin.x not the center. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `self.center` instead of using `self.frame.origin.x` and `self.frame.origin.y` then later you're setting your translation and adding it to the lastLocation.

Effectively what's happening is that your view is calculating the position changed from the center of the view, as if you were perfectly dragging from that location and then translating + lastLocation. I'm sure just by reading that you're aware of the issue.

The fix is simple.

```
self.frame.origin.x = translation.x
self.frame.origin.y = translation.y
```

The difference is the starting calculation with the translation. Origin will grab the x/y position based on where the touch event begins. Whereas the `.center` always goes from the center.